# Does JPEG compression is lossy or not?

Tags: imageprocessing

As I know, generally, the JPEG is consist of DCT, Q ,Huff.

But I'm not sure which one is lossy? all of them? of just Q?

I think  Q is lossy but else not. I just want to know that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a general image compression question with no EE specific content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantization stage is the lossy one, a number of bits is assigned to a certain DCT coefficient. The ones which are not noticeable to the human eye are assigned the least amount of bits.